# function with vector R - argument is of length zero

Tags: r, function, vector

Wrote this function `lockdown_func(beta.hat_func)`.

First thing is: I get an error "argument is of length zero".
Second thing is: when I compute it without the date indices, it doesn't change the value as it should, output vector contains same value for every indices.

```
date= c(seq(from=30, to=165))
beta.hat_func <- c(rep(x = beta.hat, times = 135))
beta.hat <- beta0[which.min(SSE)]


#implement function for modeling
lockdown_func <- function(beta.hat_func,l){
  h=beta.hat_func
  {
    for(i in 1:length(h))
      if(date[i]>60 | date[i]<110){
        beta.hat_func[i]=beta.hat_func[i]*exp(-l*(date[i]-date[i-1]))
    }else{
    beta.hat_func[i]=beta.hat_func[i]
    }
  return(h)  
  }
}

lockdown_func(beta.hat_func,0.03)
```

Comment: Can you make this reproducible for us by defining `date` and `beta.hat` ?

Comment: Of course! Just added them, beta.hat is the result of a SSE estimation and is a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few comments:

- did you mean to apply an AND rather than an OR to get  date range between 60 and 110?  This would be `date[i]>60 && date[i]<110` (it's better to use the double-`&&` if you are computing a length-1 logical value)
- because you didn't, `i=1` satisfies the criterion, so `date[i-1]` will refer to `date[0]`, which is a length-0 vector.

You might want something like:

```
l_dates <- date>60 & date<110  ## single-& here for vectorized operation
beta.hat_func[l_dates] <- beta.hat_func[l_dates]*exp(-l*diff(date)[l_dates])
```